# bookdown references working in pdf but not html

Tags: r, pandoc, bookdown

I have a bookdown project where some references are correctly processed for pdf but not for html. For example, this markup:

> Authors and modelers have successfully used this framework to derive models that have won Kaggle competitions [@Raimondi2010], have been implemented in diagnostic tools [@jahani2016comparison,@luo2016automatically], are being used as the backbone of investment algorithms [@stankovic2015investment], and are being used as a screening tool to assess the safety of new pharmaceutical products [@thomson2011not].

produces this in html

> Authors and modelers have successfully used this framework to derive models that have won Kaggle competitions (Raimondi 2010), have been implemented in diagnostic tools ***(Jahani and Mahdavi 2016,@luo2016automatically)***, are being used as the backbone of investment algorithms (Stanković, Marković, and Stojanović 2015), and are being used as a screening tool to assess the safety of new pharmaceutical products (Thomson et al. 2011).

and this in pdf

> Authors and modelers have successfully used this framework to derive models that have won Kaggle competitions (Raimondi, 2010), have been implemented in diagnostic tools ***(Jahani and Mahdavi, 2016, Luo (2016))***, are being used as the backbone of investment algorithms (Stanković et al., 2015), and are being used as a screening tool to assess the safety of new pharmaceutical products (Thomson et al., 2011).

A reprex can be found [here](https://github.com/topepo/bookdown_ref_issue) and my system uses:

```
## R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
## Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
## Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
## 
## Locale: en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / C / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8
## 
## Package version:
##   base64enc_0.1.3 bookdown_0.11.1 digest_0.6.19   evaluate_0.14  
##   glue_1.3.1      graphics_3.6.0  grDevices_3.6.0 highr_0.8      
##   htmltools_0.3.6 jsonlite_1.6    knitr_1.23      magrittr_1.5   
##   markdown_1.0    methods_3.6.0   mime_0.7        Rcpp_1.0.1     
##   rmarkdown_1.13  stats_3.6.0     stringi_1.4.3   stringr_1.4.0  
##   tinytex_0.13    tools_3.6.0     utils_3.6.0     xfun_0.7       
##   yaml_2.2.0

> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘2.0.5’
```

(edit - pandoc version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple citations must be separated by semicolons instead of commas, e.g.,

```
[@jahani2016comparison; @luo2016automatically]
```

See [Pandoc's manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citations) for the official documentation and examples.